# Facebook AS3 SDK without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, sdk

I am developing an AS3 flash file, which is to be distributed across a few web pages. Each web page randomly loads one of a pool of flash files. Much like adverts on web pages.

I only have control over my flash file and would like to use the AS3 Facebook SDK in it.
However the official AS3 SDK uses JavaScript on the HTML page on which the SWF is embedded.

I do not have control over the HTML page the SWF goes on and so cannot use this JavaScript.

Is there a way to use the Facebook API purely in AS3, so it can be used as a standalone SWF with no HTML parent page with JS on.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, I'm afraid, you always need the js call to Facebook `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` in order to login at least.